# How do I extract a RAR archive in Linux

Tags: linux, rar

How can we extract a .rar archive in Linux?

Comment: Normally, I would be this crass, but did you really bother trying to find out? http://www.google.com/search?q=linux+rar

Comment: For *nix questions also try http://unix.stackexchange.com and http://askubuntu.com (if appropriate) :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, download `unrar` from [here](http://packages.sw.be/unrar/).

Then use the following command :

```
unrar x -o- -y file.rar /usr/local/file/
```

Answer (score 2):

In a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install unrar-free
```

Then:

```
unrar x blah.rar
```

Comment: "sudo: apt-get: command not found"

Comment: User stated Linux, not a particular distribution - if its not a Debian derivative, probably won't have apt-get.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to bother with the terminal, you can download the engrampa package for your distribution or file-roller.

Depending of your linux, I will tell you how to get them.